# Jquery ui Dialog Modal True

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am use jQuery v1.8.2 and
jQuery UI v1.9.2.

so My Problem is that.

On Button click event
i have close the dialog

```
$('#oldInvoiceDialogDiv').dialog('close');
```

But Modal Property Remaining

Means after close dialog do not working like ui-widget-overlay property
Dialog

```
$("#oldInvoiceDialogDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        resizable : false,
        width : 855,
        modal : true,
        close : function(ev, ui) {

        }
    });
```

so What is my Fault.
Please tell me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing anything in your close callback function remove it.
If you do want to use it i think that this function should return Boolean at the end so try to add return true statement.

**EDIT**

***Make sure that you initialize your dialog inside document ready handler:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#oldInvoiceDialogDiv").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            resizable : false,
            width : 200,
            height:200,
            modal : true,
            buttons: {
                "Close Dialog" : function(){
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close : function(ev, ui) {
                alert("in Close");
                return true;    
            }
        });
    $('#btnOpen').click(function(){
         $("#oldInvoiceDialogDiv").dialog("open");
    })
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWyuU/1/), i think it exactly your case.